# Docker Compose - Can't access Database

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

My Docker Wordpress Container some how cannot connect to my database container. I tried to pass the credentials through the `environment` key.

I'm using external volumes that stores the Data from my previous Wordpress build as well as the data from the Database.

#### docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: db
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=wordpress_oxygen
    volumes:
      - wordpress_db-data:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - conturas-network

  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: wordpress:5.6.0-fpm-alpine
    container_name: wordpress
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      - WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=db:3306
      - WORDPRESS_DB_USER=$MYSQL_USER
      - WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=$MYSQL_PASSWORD
      - WORDPRESS_DB_NAME=wordpress_oxygen
    volumes:
      - wordpress_data:/var/www/html
    networks:
      - conturas-network

  webserver:
    depends_on:
      - wordpress
    image: nginx:1.19.6-alpine
    container_name: webserver
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - wordpress_data:/var/www/html
      - ./nginx-conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - certbot-etc:/etc/letsencrypt
    networks:
      - conturas-network

  certbot:
    depends_on:
      - webserver
    image: certbot/certbot
    container_name: certbot
    volumes:
      - certbot-etc:/etc/letsencrypt
      - wordpress_data:/var/www/html
    command: certonly --webroot --webroot-path=/var/www/html --email username@xyz.io --agree-tos --no-eff-email --force-renewal -d xyz.io -d www.xyz.io

volumes:
  certbot-etc:
  wordpress_data:
    external: true
  wordpress_db-data:
    external: true
networks:
  conturas-network:
    driver: bridge
```

#### Error Logs from the db-container

```
...

2020-12-27T15:53:26.593191Z 2 [Note] Access denied for user 'wordpress_oxygen'@'172.30.0.3' (using password: YES)
```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Could you boil your question down to the actual issue, maybe provide (only) a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?
Right now the question is very long but most of it is likely not really relevant to your actual problem...

Comment: Tip 1: set fixed IP addresses for containers, Tip 2: create an individual container for database, because currently you always create a new database container in every docker-compose up

Comment: Thanks @AdamP. I will keep that in mind, I will also change something tomorrow morning in my initial question, because I noticed that I did a mistake with the code reference. I used existing Volumes and did not  referenced this in the code block.

Answer (score 0):

The very last line of the logs give the important hint on the underlying issue:

> [Note] Access denied for user 'wordpress_oxygen'@'172.30.0.3' (using password: YES)

It means that the database credentials used to connect to the database are incorrect - i.e. the username/password combination.

But since this is logged by the database it means WordPress is actually able to connect to the database - i.e. your `docker` networks are setup correctly.

You should verify now that the values of configured credentials (`WORDPRESS_DB_USER`, `WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD` etc.) are actually correct - which is the same as `MYSQL_USER` and `MYSQL_PASSWORD` used **at the time of initializing the database** - that is, the environment variables `MYSQL_USER`, `MYSQL_PASSWORD` etc. are only used when the database volume is empty and needs to be initialized, see [*Environment Variables* in the image description](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql):

> Do note that none of the variables below will have any effect if you start the container with a data directory that already contains a database: any pre-existing database will always be left untouched on container startup.

You may also try to re-initialize the database by deleting the volume and starting a fresh instance of the service.

---

Also note that [`environment`](https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-spec/blob/master/spec.md#environment) and [`env_file`](https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-spec/blob/master/spec.md#env_file) two different ways of specifying environment variables for *the service*, but mixing those two is bad practice since it can lead to unexpected behavior.

If you want to import values from your [`.env` file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/env-file/) to use for [variable substitution](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#substitute-environment-variables-in-compose-files) you don't need to "import" it with `env_file` since it is loaded automatically for *`docker-compose`*! I.e. your current configuration does not do what you probably think it does.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, could you maybe try to explain, why it is possible to connect the wordpress on my mysql database with different credentials (like you mentioned, the initial credentials)  than the mysql database it self ?

Comment: Well, the networking seems to be set up correctly such that from your wordpress container mysql is reachable on port `db:3306` via the network. But _able to connect_ here only means _establish a TCP connection_ and not to _open a database connection_ which fails due to wrong credentials used by wordpress.
So you need to distinguish the _successful connections_ between the different layers here.

Comment: Yes you're right, but what I really don't get is, how it's possible that my `WORDPRESS_DB_USER ` can be different from my `MYSQL_USER` which exists in my .env file. I hope I expressed my self well :/

Comment: I suspect they actually are _not_ different. You can check this with [`docker inspect`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/inspect/).
But after the database volume is initialized once the credentials are stored there. Changing `MYSQL_PASSWORD` in the `.env` _afterwards_ will have no effect on the database - and I suspect that is what happened here.
I expanded my answer with a link to the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

#### What I did to fix the issue

I removed the the `environment` keys from the whole compose file.

#### Why did I do this?

I realized with the help of @acran answers, that the volume that I passed into the docker-compose file, was already a ready to use copy of my Initial Wordpress build/installation the same goes for the MySQL Database. (This means all credentials was already stored inside of each volume) Because of that I was not able to pass environment-variables to the composition, to be more precise, you can pass environment-variables to a build but they would simple have no effect on the finished container build.

**You can only set environment-variables at the initial build.**

#### Result

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: db
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - wordpress_db-data:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - my-network

  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: wordpress:5.6.0-fpm-alpine
    container_name: wordpress
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - wordpress_data:/var/www/html
    networks:
      - my-network

  webserver:
    depends_on:
      - wordpress
    image: nginx:1.19.6-alpine
    container_name: webserver
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - wordpress_data:/var/www/html
      - ./nginx-conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - certbot-etc:/etc/letsencrypt
    networks:
      - my-network

  certbot:
    depends_on:
      - webserver
    image: certbot/certbot
    container_name: certbot
    volumes:
      - certbot-etc:/etc/letsencrypt
      - wordpress_data:/var/www/html
    command: certonly --webroot --webroot-path=/var/www/html --email my.name@xyz.io --agree-tos --no-eff-email --expand  --noninteractive -d xyz.io -d www.xyz.io -d dev.xyz.io

volumes:
  certbot-etc:
  wordpress_data:
    external: true
  wordpress_db-data:
    external: true

networks:
  my-network:
    driver: bridge
```

Comment: Actually this explanation is a bit misleading: 1. There are no images _built_ here but pulled and used as is. 2. You _can_ change environment variables for services and they _will_ take effect as soon as you restart/recreate the service. 3. That the credentials are stored in the volumes is _not generally_ true.
All of this (1.-3.) only looks so because of the [specific way the entrypoint of the mysql image](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/1612c574f921f7f1afc13763ce9011fd8e130b19/5.7/docker-entrypoint.sh#L350-L356) initializes the volume with a new database and stored credentials

Comment: Okay now I'm really confused :/ . I mid take a break on this topic and coming back to it in a few hours /days.